# Gatsby "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource" when retrieving markdown from Contentful

Tags: javascript, markdown, gatsby, contentful

I'm using the gatsby starter blog template, I have successfully managed to get rich text from contentful and display it on a page. I'm now trying to do the same thing but with markdown but I'm getting an error "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource." from my graphql query.

I'm trying to follow the docs here, so to begin I have a Long text field used to store the markdown in contentful called "bodym".

[image]

My GraphQL query is below, I'm basically trying to follow the [example](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-contentful/). I can get as far as querying out the markdown from contentful.

[image]

However, when trying to convert it into usable HTML I get the error:

[image]

I get the following in the console:

```
 ERROR 

The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined

  Error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Recei  ved type undefined

  - validators.js:125 validateString
    internal/validators.js:125:11

  - index.js:68 _callee$
    [faesel-blog]/[gatsby-remark-relative-images]/index.js:68:40

  - index.js:5 asyncGeneratorStep
    [faesel-blog]/[gatsby-remark-relative-images]/index.js:5:103

  - index.js:7 _next
    [faesel-blog]/[gatsby-remark-relative-images]/index.js:7:194

  - index.js:7 
    [faesel-blog]/[gatsby-remark-relative-images]/index.js:7:364

  - new Promise

  - index.js:7 
    [faesel-blog]/[gatsby-remark-relative-images]/index.js:7:97

  - index.js:96 
    [faesel-blog]/[gatsby-remark-relative-images]/index.js:96:22

  - new Promise

  - index.js:47
    [faesel-blog]/[gatsby-remark-relative-images]/index.js:47:12

  - Array.map

  - index.js:46 module.exports
    [faesel-blog]/[gatsby-remark-relative-images]/index.js:46:22
```

My code can be found [here](https://github.com/faesel/faesel-blog/tree/markdown-blog).

Considering I'm able to retrieve the markdown from contentful. I'm guessing the problem lies somewhere in **gatsby-source-contentful** plugin. appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this is a problem with package dependencies, the codebase was originally from a gatsby starter, to resolve this i changed over the package dependencies to the following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@contentful/rich-text-from-markdown": "^14.1.1",
    "@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer": "^13.2.0",
    "gatsby": "^2.3.3",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.0.12",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.0.11",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.0.32",
    "gatsby-remark-images": "^3.0.10",
    "gatsby-remark-relative-images": "^0.2.2",
    "gatsby-source-contentful": "^2.0.47",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.0.28",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.3.8",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0"
  },
```

Then upgraded the dependencies to the following:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@contentful/rich-text-from-markdown": "^14.1.1",
    "@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer": "^13.4.0",
    "gatsby": "^2.23.11",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.3.6",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.3.6",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.6.14",
    "gatsby-remark-images": "^3.3.13",
    "gatsby-remark-relative-images": "^0.2.3",
    "gatsby-source-contentful": "^2.3.18",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.3.14",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.8.19",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1"
  }
```

This seemed to fix the problem.